# Can't install tensorflow on windows 7 32-bit

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-7

I can't install TensorFlow in Windows 7, Python 3(32-bit, Lenovo ThinkPad X201s).
When I type `pip3 install tensorflow`:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
C:\Users\sjkim>pip3 install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from 
versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow

C:\Users\sjkim>
```

And I also have 2 python versions.
How can I install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow is only tested and supported for 64-bit, x86 systems. I don't believe you can install TensorFlow through pip or conda normally from a 32-bit system.
You CAN run a linux docker container thought docker for windows, but it is based on vm and it didn't support gpu.

I have provided a 32 bit tensorflow built for windows https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers, although it's not a helpful thing.

32-bit process can use only 2GB memory; a complex model would not load.